# Is there a way to block new types of entities in my index

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I have defined

```
dynamic "false"
```

in my _default mapping tag.
This restricts new fields from being created.
Is there a way to restrict new document types (entity type) to be created?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the `_default_` mapping settings:

```
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic": "strict"
    },
    "test": {
.....
```

Complete test with 1.7.1:

```
DELETE test
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic": "strict"
    },
    "test": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "field2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "field3": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Successful test:

```
POST /test/test/1
{"field1":"abc","field2":"abc","field3":"abc"}
```

Failed test (adding a new field to an already created type):

```
POST /test/test/2
{"field1":"abc","field4":"abc"}

{
   "error": "StrictDynamicMappingException[mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [field4] within [test] is not allowed]",
   "status": 400
}
```

Failed test (creating a new type):

```
POST /test/test2/3
{"whatever":"some useless text"}

{
   "error": "StrictDynamicMappingException[mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [whatever] within [test2] is not allowed]",
   "status": 400
}
```

Comment: this will block new fields but not new entities

Comment: No, that's incorrect. I've updated my answer with a test. Used 1.7.1 for this.